# Is it possible to dynamically query Google APIs to see how much of the limit/quota you've used?

Tags: google-api, google-classroom

For a given Google API, is there any way to *dynamically* check usage against any of the current limits for that API?

For example, this page https://developers.google.com/classroom/limits?hl=en shows that I can query the Classrooms API 4,000,000 times per client per day. At midday, without going to the API Console, how could I know that I've already hit 3 million queries?

I'm hoping that there's a billing or usage API that covers this, but can't see it.

**Note:** I'm not having any issue right now with a specific call, just anticipating that my usage will scale up significantly in the next few months, so am looking for a solution for monitoring rather than advice on not hitting the limits at all. My specific use-case is for Google Classrooms, but reading wider around this I can't see a general solution either.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/monitoring

Comment: @RafaGuillermo No, that isn't dynamic (i.e. programmatic), unless you're suggesting scraping the dashboards. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*No, dynamically you can't retrieve this information.*

#### Feature Request:

You can however let Google know that this is a feature that is important for the Google Workspace APIs to have, and that you would like to request they implement it.

The page to file a Feature Request for the Google Classroom API is [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191645&template=823908), as there is no specific component for Google Workspace APIs in general I would suggest filing it here instead.

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. Raised at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177799270

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google's Cloud Monitoring API to achieve this. This is the documentation page for APIs-
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3

This is the documentation page for concerned metrics-
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#serviceruntime/quota/allocation/usage
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#serviceruntime/quota/exceeded
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#serviceruntime/quota/limit